# Is it possible to evaluate similarity (as in Kolmogorov-Smirnov test) between two sample vectors using copulas?

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test, similarities, copula

Consider the Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test: given 2 vectors of samples $X$ and $Y$ it is possible to test whether they are drawn from the same continuous distribution by calling (in R, for example):

```
ks.test(X, Y)
```

I am wondering and asking here if there is a similar test that answers the same question but uses copulas to exploit the information of the joint behaviour of $X$ and $Y$.

The idea would be to iterate, by keeping $X$ fixed, over many $Y_i$ vectors the test and find which $Y_i$ are more "similar" to $X$ considering also the information on the joint behaviour

```
#iteration i
test(X, Y_i)
```

Ideally, the test I'm looking for, would evaluate the similarity between $X$ and $n$ $Y_i$s vectors and find the $k$ (with $k<=n$) more similar to $X$.

Comment: Are X and Y individually univariate? For instance, is X = [1,2,3] and Y = [4,5,6] along the lines of what you have in mind?

Comment: Yes they are. They are time series of the rate of change of a variable. Time is not considered

Comment: First, I think it could a big mistake to ignore the time series nature of your data, but it's on you to decide if you want to assume independence of the Xi observations and independence of the Yi observations. Second, there is nothing multivariate going on here, so copula does not apply.